# Limit of multiple integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\rho>0$ and $B_\rho=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\mid x^2+y^2\leq \rho^2 \}$. Let $u(x,y)$ be a $C^3$ two variables real function and the equality $u_{xx}(0,0)+u_{yy}(0,0)=0$ hold. Find $$\lim_{\rho \to 0}\frac{1}{\rho^2}|u(0,0) -\frac{1}{\pi\rho^2}\int\int_{B_{\rho}}u(x,y)dxdy|.$$

I think Taylor expansion of $u(x,y)$ may be useful, but  I don't know how to use it. Please give me an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Indeed Taylor expand at $(0,0)$: $$u(x,y)=u(0,0)+x u_x + yu_y + \frac{1}{2}(x^2u_{xx} + 2xy u_{xy} +  y^2u_{yy}) + \frac{1}{3!}(x^3 u_{xxx} + ... + y^3 u_{yyy}) + R_3(x,y)$$ Calculate the value for each term (use that the ball is symmetric) and show that the last term drops out in the limit.

Side-remark: If you divide only by $\rho$ and not $\rho^2$ outside the paranthesis then the limit is in fact a way of extracting the value of the Laplacian (times a const) at a given point for a $C^2$ function.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.